# Azure Cron Schedule to trigger every second week on Monday (trigger one Monday and not the other, repeat)

Tags: azure, cron, azure-functions, cron-task, crontrigger

Is it possible to schedule a function in azure to run every second week on a specific day of the week, example Monday?
Or at least to run on the first Monday of every month?

I try something like
`0 0 1-7,15-21 1 * 1`
but it runs on every 1-7 and 15-21 AND Mondays. I want to change that for 1-7 and 15-21 that IS Monday.

Comment: What does `every second week on a specific day of the week` mean, could you please express it more clearly

Comment: Seems the structure of your cron expression is not right. And please explain clearly.:)

Comment: {second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day of week}

Comment: Every second week meaning that it will run one week and does not run in the next. One week on one week off, in a specific day, so run one Monday and does not run on the next

Comment: @FrankGong, sorry I cannot accept your answer as you did not answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't think of a way to do what you are asking "elegantly". It does look like Azure accepts TimeSpan strings as inputs. So if you wanted your function to run every two weeks (not a specific day of the week) you can use the following:

```
[TimerTrigger("14.00:00:00")]
```

If you wanted to run every 2 weeks starting on a specific day of the week, you can simply publish your function on the specific day of the week that you are concerned with.

Let's say you also wanted to run your function the day that you published it, you can set your `TimerTrigger` like so:

```
[TimerTrigger("14.00:00:00", RunOnStartup = true)]
```

then publish your function the same day.

This is more of a hack to do what you are asking, 8 months later this is all you've got :)

If you wanted to do this a little more programmatically, you could use a `TimerTrigger` like

```
[TimerTrigger("0 0 0 * * Monday")]
```

the when your function executes, check if you are on a even or odd numbered week and return early - effectively running once every two weeks:

```
if ((DateTime.Now.DayOfYear / 7) % 2 == 0) return;
```